# PRF-values at entity-level for SpaCy NER model

Tags: performance, entity, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I have a question regarding the evaluation of a SpaCy NER model with the help of the function `scorer`: are the performance results at entity- or token-level?

If the latter, I would be grateful to be proffered some hints about how can I find the prf-values at entity-level.

Also, if the context is helpful, here is how I implemented an evaluation function:
https://github.com//discussions/8178.

Thanks in advance!